# Rails same app with different databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a report app in Rails for a current desktop app. The app is kind of pos/accounting.

So at the moment there are different clients with the desktop app installed at shop or office. Each one has its own mysql database.

I am now planning how to setup the server, most probably heroku.

Given that I will keep the databases for each client separated, I'm trying to understand the best path to follow.

Another thing to consider is that there will be different version of the app, i.e. restaurant, bar, shop etc.. Different versions will use the same database. I'll just need to change some controller and view. Most probably I'll handle this using namespace.

For a client(company) multiple users will have access to the app.

The solution I thought is to create a database table company and add a column company to users table.

Things that could change from a client to another:

- call different images from assets such as logo
- there might be custom views or even controller if a client requests some customization
- use different database
- domain possibly, but that's not that important wouldn't a be a big deal to use the same

Then based on user.company show a different logo or any other required image, render a view instead of another, at login connect to the proper database.

I don't know yet how to implement it, right now I'm still evaluating the best approach to follow. But this way maintenance/updates would be easy to manage even if maybe performance will be a bit lower and code harder to understand with possible customizations all together but that's acceptable.

Is this a reasonable solution or should I consider something different? Am I missing something important to consider?

Comment: Are you familiar with the apartment gem? https://github.com/influitive/apartment You might also be interested in Ryan Bigg's book - https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails

Comment: apartment seems promising i'll look into it thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/zendesk/active_record_shards   Also try sharding gem